# Class with custom rule in OWL ontology

Tags: owl, ontology, fuseki, apache-jena

I have created an ontology using Protege.

**Classes -**

```
Person
   Man
   Woman
```

**Properties(Domain / Range)**

```
Knows(Person / Person)
  hasRelationShip(Person / Person)
    hasParent(Person / Person)
      hasFather(Person / Man)
      hasMother(Person / Woman)
    hasChild(Person / Person)
      hasSon(Person / Man)
      hasDaughter(Person / Woman)
```

Now I imported this ontology in jena fuseki. which is configured with OWLMiniFBRuleReasoner and then created some instance.

**I have following instance tripple**

```
:Ravi rdf:type :Man .
:Anjani rdf:type :Man .
:Indra rdf:type :Woman .
:Ravi :hasFather :Anjani .
:Ravi :hasMother :Indra .
```

Now if i query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?a ?b WHERE { 
  ?a :hasParent ?b
}
```

I get result

```
:Ravi - :Anjani
:Ravi - :Indra
```

If I query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?a ?b WHERE { 
              ?a :hasChild ?b
            }
```

I get result -

```
:Indra - :Ravi
:Anjani - :Ravi
```

But if query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?a ?b WHERE { 
      ?a :hasSon ?b
    }
```

I don't get any result for obvious reason.

So the question is, is there a way to tell reasoner -

```
If (?a :hasChild ?b) and (?b rdf:type :Man)
Then ?a :hasSon ?b
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Assuming you are using simply OWL you can model it in Protege like this:

- Create an object property `R_Man`
- Go to class Man. Section `EquivalentTo` add:

  `R_Man some Self`
- Go to the property `hasSon`. Section `SuperPropertyOf (Chain)`, add:

  `hasChild o R_Man`

Unfortunately, this will give you a Cyclic Dependency error. I know it is not ideal, but if you define `hasSon` and `hasDaughter` not to be subproperties of `hasChild`, it will give you the expected result.